# How to specify this font in beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex, fontspec, templates

How to specify the font used in the following figure in my beamer document? By the way, I am using `XeLaTeX`.

[image: font-want]

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS} 
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{serif}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[]{Font}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Transactional vs. non-transactional}
  \begin{center}
    transactional vs. non-transactional
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image: font]

Comment: You don’t say which font, but one way would be to use the `professionalfonts` package option and `\setmainfont`.

Comment: @Davislor I mean the font of the text like "Transactional vs. non-transactional" in the figure. I want to know how to set it in beamer.

Comment: Looks like Gill Sans.

Comment: I second that: The lowercase `t` very much looks like Gill Sans

Comment: @Davislor Thanks. However, it seems not the font.